# Extract posts from wordpress blog to another site

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having a site where i would like to show posts from other blogs. I want to integrate it into my website, therefore i need to scale down the images and place it inside and div. I know i get get the content from the blog /feed?=json, but since i need a little more freedom on the image size, what would be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

You want to post from a feed into WP directly? If you want work with the content and image size, you might need to add new posts per article.

Comment: I want to post the feed into another page. i'm thinking about creating a webservice posting the feeds into mysql database, but that would give a full html code of the text and images, but the proportions on my page is not the same as that wordpress blog i need the feed from. therefore i need a way to resize it programatically. What would be the best solution?

Comment: You might be able to go from RSS into WP, but I don't think it will resize automatically. Try a service like ifttt.com